# Regex string without double letter

Tags: javascript, regex

My question is what can be a valid `regex` for strings that don't contain a double letter.
My solution is : `b(ab)*a + a(ba)*b .`

But i don't think it is correct, because it doesn't include the `a` or `b`. 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a negative lookahead:

```js
const re = /^(?!.*?(.).*?\1)[a-z]*$/g;

let s1 = "abcdefgh", s2 = "abcdefga";

console.log(re.test(s1));
console.log(re.test(s2));
```

How it works:

```
/^(?!.*?(.).*?\1)[a-z]*$/g
```

- `^` asserts position at start of the string
- Negative Lookahead `(?!.*?(.).*?\1)`: Assert that the Regex below does not match

  - `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)
  - `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed
  - 1st Capturing Group `(.)`
  - `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)
  - `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)
  - `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed
- `\1` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
- Match a single character present in the list below `[a-z]*`

  - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `a-z` a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
- `$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)
  Global pattern flags
- `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)

[image]